# Adding rows when using .apply()

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to apply an "aggregation" function to a groupby instance of a DataFrame by which the result is not reducing the final number of rows, but increasing it (not quite an "aggregation"). For instance, the below call should result in a duplication of cat=A, B rows depending on the result returned by the function (with `cola` and `colb` columns). Unfortunately, the added index columns are somehow added as columns in the result.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
  'date': pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=10, freq='10D'),
  'val': range(10),
  'cat': ['A'] * 7 + ['B'] * 3
})

>>> def func(x):
        data = range(20)
        # 2 x 10 = 20 rows
        index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
          [3, 4], pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=10, freq='10D')
        ], names=['cola', 'colb'])
        return pd.Series(data, index=index)

>>> df.groupby('cat').apply(func)
cola          3                                                         \
colb 2018-01-01 2018-01-11 2018-01-21 2018-01-31 2018-02-10 2018-02-20   
cat                                                                      
A             0          1          2          3          4          5   
B             0          1          2          3          4          5   

cola                                                      4             \
colb 2018-03-02 2018-03-12 2018-03-22 2018-04-01 2018-01-01 2018-01-11   
cat                                                                      
A             6          7          8          9         10         11   
B             6          7          8          9         10         11   

cola                                                                    \
colb 2018-01-21 2018-01-31 2018-02-10 2018-02-20 2018-03-02 2018-03-12   
cat                                                                      
A            12         13         14         15         16         17   
B            12         13         14         15         16         17   

cola                        
colb 2018-03-22 2018-04-01  
cat                         
A            18         19  
B            18         19
```

Is there anything I can do to get this done or is `.apply()` just not geared to duplicate rows?

Comment: It can do what you need it to do.  However, you have not specified what it is you need it to do.  Show us what the results should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC: you don't want to return a Series.  Return a DataFrame instead.

```
def func(x):
    data = range(20)
    # 2 x 10 = 20 rows
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
      [3, 4], pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=10, freq='10D')
    ], names=['cola', 'colb'])
    return pd.DataFrame(dict(Stuff=data), index=index)

df.groupby('cat').apply(func)

                     Stuff
cat cola colb             
A   3    2018-01-01      0
         2018-01-11      1
         2018-01-21      2
         2018-01-31      3
         2018-02-10      4
         2018-02-20      5
         2018-03-02      6
         2018-03-12      7
         2018-03-22      8
         2018-04-01      9
    4    2018-01-01     10
         2018-01-11     11
         2018-01-21     12
         2018-01-31     13
         2018-02-10     14
         2018-02-20     15
         2018-03-02     16
         2018-03-12     17
         2018-03-22     18
         2018-04-01     19
B   3    2018-01-01      0
         2018-01-11      1
         2018-01-21      2
         2018-01-31      3
         2018-02-10      4
         2018-02-20      5
         2018-03-02      6
         2018-03-12      7
         2018-03-22      8
         2018-04-01      9
    4    2018-01-01     10
         2018-01-11     11
         2018-01-21     12
         2018-01-31     13
         2018-02-10     14
         2018-02-20     15
         2018-03-02     16
         2018-03-12     17
         2018-03-22     18
         2018-04-01     19
```

---

Alternatively, you can keep your Series and use `pd.concat`

```
def func(x):
    data = range(20)
    # 2 x 10 = 20 rows
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
      [3, 4], pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=10, freq='10D')
    ], names=['cola', 'colb'])
    return pd.Series(data, index=index)

pd.concat({key: func(value) for key, value in df.groupby('cat')})

   cola  colb      
A  3     2018-01-01     0
         2018-01-11     1
         2018-01-21     2
         2018-01-31     3
         2018-02-10     4
         2018-02-20     5
         2018-03-02     6
         2018-03-12     7
         2018-03-22     8
         2018-04-01     9
   4     2018-01-01    10
         2018-01-11    11
         2018-01-21    12
         2018-01-31    13
         2018-02-10    14
         2018-02-20    15
         2018-03-02    16
         2018-03-12    17
         2018-03-22    18
         2018-04-01    19
B  3     2018-01-01     0
         2018-01-11     1
         2018-01-21     2
         2018-01-31     3
         2018-02-10     4
         2018-02-20     5
         2018-03-02     6
         2018-03-12     7
         2018-03-22     8
         2018-04-01     9
   4     2018-01-01    10
         2018-01-11    11
         2018-01-21    12
         2018-01-31    13
         2018-02-10    14
         2018-02-20    15
         2018-03-02    16
         2018-03-12    17
         2018-03-22    18
         2018-04-01    19
dtype: int64
```

Comment: You are welcome.  See my update to see if it better suits your needs.